# Delete custom dimension from Google Analytics tracker

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I am setting custom dimensions values using `[GAITracker set:value:]` method. This works fine but now I want to remove / delete the custom dimension values from the tracker so they do not get tracked with further requests.

I can use `nil` for the value. But it does not remove the custom dimension. The request still contains it but with null value. See the except below.

```
GoogleAnalytics 3.16 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        ...
        "&cd14" = "<null>";
        "&cd3" = "<null>";
        ...
        gaiVersion = "3.16";
        useSecure = 0;
    };
    timestamp = "2017-05-26 09:43:11 +0000";
}
```

Is there a way to remove custom dimensions completely? In other words, is there a way I can have no "&cd14" and "&cd3" in further requests?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found on internet, is to set `nil` to every customDimension, after `send:` method of the `tracker` is called.